# UIWebView get HTML Source

Tags: html, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I am trying to get the HTML source of a UIWebView without re-downloading it again (a.k.a. do another download, such as `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL*)URL]` or launching an NSURLRequest. Browsing the UIWebView header and documentation, there seems to be no way of accessing the current loaded NSData of the source. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I have this same question since my webview comes out blank in some cases and I would like to see if there is html in there.  I think [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script] could be a start, but I have no idea what javascript would bring back the entire document.

Comment: As the answer below says, it's easier to do the inverse (get the data, then load it into the web view). I wrote a wrapper class for downloading the data (makes it simpler, and you also get the MIME type) if anyone wants it just comment and I will post it as an answer if it doesn't fit in a comment.
However I do wonder how you can make the the back/forward buttons work. Can somebody tell me ?

Comment: @Alexandre Cassagne, can you please post your wrapper class or post it at http://snipplr.com/ ? This is what I'm needing since I can't get the html source/data the other way I planned. Thanks

Comment: yeah, I`m not on my Mac right now, but will send it to you asap. It's just a simple way to use NSURLRequest, nothing to fancy

Comment: There you go guys, I added a test app to demo it. Nothing too fancy, but it's there
PS: if anyone knows how to do the preprocessor thing to determine if it will compile for iOS or Mac OS

Comment: Silly me , I forgot to put the link --' 
https://github.com/AlexandreCassagne/SimpleRequestDownload
Could someone tell me if it works as it should ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse should do what you want. That is, load the URL into an NSData object and then load the UIWebView from that object using `– loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:`

Answer (score 24):

UIWebView can execute javascript code, so this can work it out.

```
NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
```

Comment: Thanks! This handles also the case where HTML is rendered from javascript.