# Getting data from html code

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode, macos

I've got a website which only shows a temperature. Now I want that Xcode loads the page and get's the temperature. 
Here is the websites code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
tempfan1:43.57
</html>
```

In Xcode I loaded the website with a WebView. The WebView now shows the website but I want to get the source code of the website and store the value of "tempfan1" into a float, but I don't know how to get the source code of the website.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIWebView get HTML Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044041/uiwebview-get-html-source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the downvotes because you did not show any research effort. I have no idea of XCode or objective-C but a quick search revealed the answer in 20 secs.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:

[UIWebView get HTML Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044041/uiwebview-get-html-source)